# Polymer Translation component -> working with shady but not shadow dom

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I've the following component:

```
<dom-module id="t-t">
    <template>
        <span id="textSpan"></span>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "t-t",
            properties: {
            },
            ready: function () {
                var content = Polymer.dom(this).childNodes[0].textContent;
                this.$.textSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(commonClient.getTranslation(content)));
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

this component works correctly with shady dom!

I use it in a header of ag-grid! with shady the result looks like this

[image: correct]

```
<span class="ag-header-cell-text">
    <t-t>
        <span id="textSpan" class="style-scope t-t">Materialstatus</span>
    </t-t>
</span>
```

If I use shadow dom it's look like this

[image: incorrect]

```
<span class="ag-header-cell-text">
    <t-t>
    #shadow-root
        <span id="textSpan">Prüfe Mindestlagerdauer</span>
    Material_CheckMinStay
    </t-t>
</span>
```

anyone any idea?

Comment: it looks like someone inserts a linebreak or anything, so the next column header starts on a newline instead of the same row! works perfectly without "shadow" dom!

Comment: I've als created afiddle wich should show the error, but in this it works... I'm very confused... https://jsfiddle.net/ucu23ox6/4/

Comment: problem is, my code also works when I use shady instead of shadow, so this should not be a style issue

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it.

Problem was not my translation component, problem was I used the grid inside another polymer component! And after enabling "shadow", the component had no access to it's styles any more (cause they wer imported in index.html)